# Calculate time taken by program to run in uefi

Tags: c, time, bios, uefi, edk2

I want to calculate how much time does my application take to run. I am trying to use ticks to calculate time elapsed. Basically using the PerformanceLib and TimerLib

```
Frequency = GetPerformanceCounterProperties(NULL, NULL);
StartTick = GetPerformanceCounter();
EndTick = GetPerformanceCounter();
ElapsedTicks = EndTick > StartTick ? EndTick - StartTick : StartTick - EndTick;
TimeInSeconds = (double)ElapsedTicks / Frequency;
```

I am getting 0 seconds everytime. Any leads for this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if `GetPerformanceCounterProperties()`  and `GetPerformanceCounter()` are returning a valid values or not?

Comment: If Frequency is a really big number, getting zero makes sense.  So what is that number typically? (`printf()` is your friend).  And are you using a type `double` to print output? (`TimeInSeconds` needs to be a `double`, for example). If not, then everything less than a whole number (ie: half a second) will always be zero because of that.   As for the code you shared, logic seems good.  So, it's not that AFAIK.  -- And this is why we're always saying, "share just enough code so we can reproduce this issue."

Comment: [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).